# what is difference in "return name;" and "return this.name"

Tags: java, junit, jacoco

I am trying the Jacco testing and I am able to test the `getStudentId` from a class called `Student` which has:

```
public String getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}
```

When I try to test my other class named `Product`, I get an error - the only difference between the two is in the `getX` method. The `getName` method of `Product` is:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

and the error message says:

> constructor Product in class Product cannot be applied to given types

Comment: The error is not in the code you posted, it's elsewhere. The way you return an attribute (with or without `this`) has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez is right. Please do show us a bigger snippet of a code, especially constructor of class Product and example of how you call this constructor in a code.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/javaunit     here is my full code for my product class , can you tell me if there's a problem in it? because it don't give me any errors. @ÓscarLópez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `this` references the instance of the object *you are currently in*. Imagine having a class like this:

```
public class A {
    private String property;

    public void changeProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property
    }
}
```

Outside of the method the variable name **property** is not ambiguous and references the member variable of class `A`. But it is ambiguous inside the method `changeProperty` because there is also the argument named **property**.

---

How does **Java** resolves this conflict? If you just type `property` you will always reference the object with a smaller scope, so the argument of the method and not the member variable. By using `this.property` you can reference the member variable again.

If there is no such conflict in your object, like in your example, then you do not need the **this** statement and `this.name` is the same as `name`.

---

However as prevention of very nasty bugs one could always use `this` when referencing a member variable, just as good practice. Imagine you would create a method with such a name conflict in the future and forget about the member variable, whoops you easily create a bug that is hard to debug.

Some programmers even go further and do always give member variables other names than arguments, to prevent such name conflicts. For example member variables are often named:

- **mProperty** or
- **_property**

---

Note that the *method* `this(...)` references a constructor of the own object. It can be used in a constructor to pass the task to another constructor like:

```
public class A {
    public A(String fileName) {
        this(new File(fileName), true);
    }

    public A(File file) {
        this(file, true);
    }

    public A(File file, boolean doSomething) {
        // Code ...
    }
}
```

---

Analogously there is also the keyword `super` which references the **parent-class**. For example:

```
public class A {
    protected String property;
}

public class B extends A {
    private String property;

    public void foo() {
        // Property of B
        System.out.println(property);
        // The same
        System.out.println(this.property);

        // Property of A
        System.out.println(super.property);
    }
}
```

This keyword can also be used to reference *parent-constructor* or other methods of the parent class.

---

So all in all it is just about **resolving** such **name conflicts**.

Now we know that, it is easy to see that the code you posted does **not contain the bug**.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this.name you are using a attribute defined in your class, the attribute name. However, when you use only name, it could be any variable called so in your code, even the attribute. Example:

```
   public String getName(){
    String name = "Mery";
    this.name = "Jacob";
    return name;
   }
```

This method return the value "Mery". If you put return this.name then you return the value "Jacob".

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance you set studentID to a public variable. Anytime you are using this.whatever to return a variable from a getX function, the this. implies it's a private variable. More likely than not the studentID is public and that's why you got away with no 'this.' in front of it.